# How to Embed DirectShow Video Player to SDL Window

Tags: c++, sdl, directshow

I'm trying to play a Video File using DirectShow library in a SDL Window, I use the library provided from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow-playback-example) and works fine when I try build it separately, but the code from main.cpp needs create a apart window in `HWND` to work and I want to use it in a existent SDL_Window.

Code from main.cpp

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"DirectShow Playback", 
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

My code

```
SDL_SysWMinfo info; 
SDL_VERSION(&info.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(g_window, &info);
HWND hwnd = GetWindow(info.info.win.window, GWL_WNDPROC);
```

I already have `SDL_Window* g_window`, `SDL_Renderer* g_renderer` and `SDL_Thread* video_tid`  but seems not work with `HWND hwnd`

Also, if I got it successfully then I will change `ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);`?

Here the complete code:

```
TUserFunc(void, PlayVideo, HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow, bool testvideo)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";
    
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

       SDL_SysWMinfo info; 
       SDL_VERSION(&info.version);
       SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(g_window, &info);
       HWND hwnd = GetWindow(info.info.win.window, GWL_WNDPROC);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        NotifyError(NULL, L"CreateWindowEx failed.");
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

PD: When I use the HWND hwnd of main.cpp the video plays but in a hidden window and the SDL window keeps completely frozen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectShow video renderers have support for so called "windowless mode" which you can utilize:

> #### [Using Windowless Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/using-windowless-mode)
>
> Windowless mode avoids these problems by having the VMR draw directly on the application window's client area, using DirectDraw to clip the video rectangle.

[Old Windows SDK](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/tree/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow) offers related samlpes (e.g. `vmr9/windowless`).

Answer (score 0):

In that OLD Windows SDK is a sample called [Cutscene](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/tree/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/players/cutscene), combining that with `put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD)` for borderless and binding it to SDL Window works perfectly, thanks